# looping array in gridview yii2 to make each column

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, gridview, yii2

I have variabel date as array like $date = [1,2,3,....,30]
I want to looping this array like in gridview like

```
column = [
for($i = 0; $i <= count($date); $i++){
[
label => $date[$i]
value => $date[$i]
]
}
]
```

Comment: You want to create an [ArrayDataProvider](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider) (Look at the first example code, you should be able to pass for `allModels` your $date array)? You can pass this to the gridview.

Comment: your question in not clear..

Comment: @scaisEdge I just want to make table header that from looping array

Comment: Add sample output you want to achieve.

Comment: just  label in column for example | Name | Email |  that can be made by gii, but  I want to add another label column that for period of month (from day 1 - 30). so maybe like this | Name | Email | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 | ........| Day 30 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column arrange something like that

```
$columns =[];
$columns[] = "name";
$columns[] = "email";
for($i = 0; $i <= count($date); $i++){
    $columns[] = [
        'label' => $date[$i]
        'value' => function ($model) use($date,$id){
            // Your magic code
        }
    ]
}
```

And pass it on GridView

```
columns => $columns
```